# ReactJS ComponentWillMount() after passing Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to ask why the child ( ComponentWillMount() ) component is only once rendered, once I am passing props to it everytime on onClick.

Once I click some button that is passing props to the child, the ComponentWillMount() of child is not triggering again, only in the first click only.

**Parent Component:**

```
render(){
return(
                <div>
                    <AppModuleForm 
                    editID = {this.state.editID}
                    editURL = {this.state.editURL}
                    editConf = {this.state.editConf}
                    editDesc = {this.state.editDesc}
                    editIcon = {this.state.editIcon}
                    editParent = {this.state.editParent}
                    editOrder= {this.state.editOrder}
                    status={this.state.status} 
                    moduleList={this.state.moduleList}  
                    updateAppModuleTree={this.updateAppModuleTree.bind(this)}/>
                </div>
)
}
```

**Child Component:**

```
constructor(props){
        super(props)
        console.log(this.props.editDesc)
        this.state={
            url:'',
            description:'',
            parentID:'',
            order:'',
            configuration:'',
            icon:'',
            parentIDList:[],
            urlDuplicate: false,
            isSuccess: false,
            errorMessage: '',
        }

    }

    componentWillMount(){
        if(this.props.status==='edit'){
            let {
                editURL,
                editDesc,
                editParent,
                editConf,
                editIcon,
                editOrder} = this.props

            this.setState({
                url:editURL,
                description:editDesc,
                parentID:editParent,
                order:editOrder,
                configuration:editConf,
                icon:editIcon,
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should really read about React components lifecycle. `componentWillMount`, as its name suggests, is called only once, before the component itself is mounted. What you are looking for is `componentWillReceiveProps`. Look it up. But some of the lifecycle functions are about to become legacy, so you really should brush up on all the new ones.

Comment: Read the doc : https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle

Comment: What I want to happen is, everytime the child component is called from other component, child should setState the props.

Answer (score 1):

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
   if(nextProps.status != this.props.status){
        if(this.props.status==='edit'){
            let {
                editURL,
                editDesc,
                editParent,
                editConf,
                editIcon,
                editOrder} = this.props

            this.setState({
                url:editURL,
                description:editDesc,
                parentID:editParent,
                order:editOrder,
                configuration:editConf,
                icon:editIcon,
            })
        }
      }
    }
```

**ComponentWillMount** is mounting lifecycle method which will be called before mounting your component hence initialisation can be done in that while **ComponentWillReceiveProps** will be called once props are changed and you will get changes in nextProps parameter.

Comment: When I am using ComponentWillRecieveProps, the change is delayed. It changing the state of child on the next fire of the button (that calling the child component)

Comment: for example: 1st Click -> I passed the props (nothing happens) 2nd Click -> It rendering the props passed of the 1st click, not the props of the 2nd click.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to read https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html
and understand where to use `props` and why you need to pass something into component `state`.

From http://lucybain.com/blog/2016/react-state-vs-pros/

> So when would you use `state`?
>
> When a component needs to keep track of information between renderings
>   the component itself can create, update, and use state.

So you shouldn't transfer to state anything that will not change internally during component live cycle. As I can see all props those you pass to component are most likely will not be changed from within the component, all callbacks and icons you should take from props in component jsx.

If you have some editable data that you pass into its props from parent, on component mount (use `componentWillMount()`) you can copy that data to component state.That means all data will be stored in component internally and will not being overwritten on every `render()` call from passed `props`. 
If you need to check if new `props` contains changes you can use `componentWillReceiveProps(newProps)` and there you can compare `newProps` with `this.props` and and process changes if needed.

Also i can suggest you to rename component callbacks handlers with respect to naming best practices:

```
<div>
            <AppModuleForm 
                handleEditID = {this.onEditID}
                handleEditURL = {this.onEditURL}
                handleEditConf = {this.onEditConf}
                handleEditDesc = {this.onEditDesc}
                handleEditIcon = {this.onEditIcon}
                handleEditParent = {this.onEditParent}
                handleEditOrder= {this.onEditOrder}
                status={this.state.status} 
                moduleList={this.state.moduleList}  
                updateAppModuleTree={this.updateAppModuleTree.bind(this)}/>
            </div>
```

And I dont see any reasonable purpose to declare or to store functions in components state. So you can consider to move your handlers `this.state.editID`
etc. to parent component `this` scope. Like that

```
onEditId = () => { /* function code */ }
```

If you use arrow function  `= () =>` it automatically binds to component `this` and you don't need to bind them manually like you do in

> {this.updateAppModuleTree.bind(this)}

After all that may be you will understand more clearly how you should manage your components life cycle and your problem will no longer be relevant.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, those properties I pass to the child, like those (ids) are state not function on the parent component. But those ids are from the other component also, I still figuring out that I will directly call the child component from other component (not on the parent). This answer is really helpful.

Comment: If I am using componentWillReceiveProps(newProps), the state of child is updating only on the second fire of the button, for example:
1st Click  -> I passed the props (nothing happens)
2nd Click -> It rendering the props passed of the 1st click, not the props of the 2nd click.